# How are the word piece, song and work used to describe music?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, phrase-meaning, phrases

After researching the use of the words: piece, work, song, I am becoming confused about how these words are used to describe music (or how they relate to music).

So far, it seems that a **work of music** = a large piece of music.

A piece of music is a smaller part of that work.  **Is that correct?**

A song is something that is sung, but a piece/work of music is composed/work. **A m I correct?.**

Yet, I can say: I have just heard a wonderful **piece/work of** music. (referring to a song ).

I suppose an English teacher might disagree with a musician about the use of these words. I would appreciate any examples or definitions to help me understand these words better.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're talking about classical music, both **work** and **piece** refer to a single, complete composition. A piece is *not* a smaller part of a work.

However, you use the word **work** more often when connecting it directly to the composer, while **piece** is used more from the point of view of the performer or the listener.  So you could say,

> I just heard a wonderful **piece** of music.  I think it's one of Beethoven's best **works**.

There I've referred to exactly the same composition as a **piece** (from the listener's point of view) and a **work** (connecting it to the composer).

[ An aside: you can use these same words with nearly any artistic creation. A painter can create a **work** (of art) and a painting can can be a **piece** (of art). ]

A **song** is indeed something that is sung, but it is also a musical **work** and a **piece** of music. Most musicians would not refer to everything that is sung as a **song** though - a song is usually relatively short (no more than a few minutes) and, in particular, has one main melody.  Beethoven's Ninth Symphony has a lot of singing in it, but it is not "a song" because it's too long and has too many melodic lines and choral sections to be properly called a song.

Comment: Good answer. I was in the middle of composing one on similar lines. There are many kinds of vocal music that are not songs - operas, and settings of the traditional words for church services, for example.

Comment: +1 on good answer. One point - there are some works, like suites, where the individual parts can be called pieces, too.

Answer (score 1):

**Work of Music**

"Work of music" is not an especially common English phrase.  It is used, but not nearly as frequently as "piece of music."

If you follow this [link to the ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=work+of+music%2C+piece+of+music&year_end=2019&year_start=1800&smoothing=3&corpus=26&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwork%20of%20music%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpiece%20of%20music%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cwork%20of%20music%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpiece%20of%20music%3B%2Cc0), you'll see that "piece of music" was 32 times more common in published works in 2019.

Of the handful of examples of "work of music" that I scanned through, a significant portion (maybe a majority) were found in philosophical discussions of music or art.

Unless you are discussing the nature of music, or of art, I would suggest avoiding the phrase "work of music"<sup>1</sup> - clearly some people use it, but some people will find it strange, whereas virtually everyone will find "piece of music" normal.

**Piece of Music**

*Piece of music* is a very general term. *Music* is a mass noun in English, so if you want to speak of a single unit of music, you have to use *piece*.  This is just the same as with other mass nouns: you can't say *a music*, just as you can't say *a software*, *an advice*, *a clothing* (it's *piece of software*, *piece of advice*, *piece/article of clothing*). So anything that you would refer to as *music* can be a *piece of music*: the so-called "Symphony of a Thousand [musicians]" or a melody you hum.

An important note: a piece of music can be referred to as "a piece" - as in, "the orchestra played **one piece** that was forty-five minutes long." We also use *piece* in this way when speaking about other works of art (i.e. you can call a dance composition or a work of visual art "a piece"), **but we would not say**, "I have a lot of software installed on this computer - Firefox is my favorite piece" and probably would not say "She gave me a lot of advice - one piece was especially useful..."

Be careful, though, a piece of pop music would probably not be referred to as "a piece."  When listening to a Beethoven album, "This is my favorite piece" will *definitely* be acceptable; when listening to a Miles Davis album "This is my favorite piece" will *probably* be acceptable; when listening to an NWA album, "This is my favorite piece" will sound pretty strange.

**Song**

As another answer points out, not everything that is sung is properly called *a song*.  And on the other hand, pieces of music without words are often called *songs*.  For example, the iTunes store has a section called "Top Songs."  It's likely that all ten of those compositions do have words, but if a piece without lyrics sneaked onto the list, they wouldn't feel the need to change the section heading to "Top Tracks."

Again, the context is important.  You're more likely to hear *song* used to refer to an instrumental piece of pop music than a classical composition without lyrics.

---

1. On the other hand, it *is* common to refer to certain musical compositions as "works."  For example, we might speak of "the works of Mozart" or "the works of Beethoven," or we might regard one of [Mozart's compositions](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Oratorio_Arias_for_Soprano/1VZwDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22a+work+of+great%22+mozart&pg=PA14&printsec=frontcover) as "a work of great beauty and power."  Calling a composition "a work" suggests a fair amount of gravitas.  We would probably not refer to a television jingle "a work" and we're more likely to write of "the works of Mozart" than "the works of Madonna."